# How to Decrypt STUN Traffic Using Wireshark for Load Testing?

Tags: jmeter, wireshark, stun

community! I'm an intern in the field of load testing, and we are conducting reliability testing on a video conferencing system similar to Skype or Zoom using JMeter.

While analyzing the traffic with WireShark, we discovered that more than 90% of the traffic consists of STUN protocol packets. We are facing challenges simulating this traffic in JMeter due to encryption.

Is it possible to decrypt STUN traffic using Wireshark so that we can successfully simulate it in JMeter? If yes, what steps and tools should be used to decode STUN packets?

Thank you for your assistance!

In my online research, I only found information on 'How to Decrypt SSL with Wireshark using a pre-master secret key.' However, the current challenge I'm facing is decrypting traffic specifically for the STUN protocol. The methods I came across for SSL decryption don't seem directly applicable to STUN. Can anyone provide guidance or resources on decrypting STUN traffic, considering its unique characteristics? I appreciate any insights or examples related to decrypting STUN packets in the context of load testing with tools like JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a STUN Java client library like [JSTUN](https://jstun.javawi.de/) or [ice4j](https://github.com/jitsi/ice4j) from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language.

Alternatively you can [develop your own JMeter plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) using one of the aforementioned libraries.